# Rails sorting columns based on belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, models

I hope the title of this is accurate enough to get help.

I'm following RailsCast #228 - http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

The sorting works exactly as described. The problem I'm having is the `:sort` param only passes through the column name. Except all my column records are linked to another Model.

For example:

- I have a model called `Ticket` that has `ID, Issue` etc..  columns.
- I have a model called `Issue` that stores my list of issues with a `name` column.

When `ID` header is clicked, it sorts list ASC or DESC prefectly by ID. 
However when I click `Issue` it's sorting `issue_id`. This isn't helpful because the `issue_id`'s aren't in alphabetical order.

How can I get it to sort by `@ticket.issue.name`?

Comment: I won't write this as an answer because its not worthy answer but please look at the following railscasts - http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables will do exactly what you want and more!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. That actually looks amazing, but he doesn't go over accessing and sorting by the associated model, so this doesn't help entirely.

Comment: Well I mean if you could produce an average table that contained the ticket.issue.name then all you would need to do is attach a class to this table and implement some of the required JS and it will take care of it all for you.